# My progress bar styles are not working?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have read 3 different tutorials on how to style a progress bar specifically for my browser (Google Chrome). Every time I try to style my progress bar however, it doesn't show when I go to test it. I have tried to copy and pasted the styling code directly from the tutorials, but to no result.

HTML:

```css
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  -webkit-appearance: progress-bar;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<progress max="100" value="50"></progress>
```

That shows a regular progress bar, as if I have done nothing to it, and I have no other progress bars in my code, just that one.

I just want to know why it is not working, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the default webkit appearance with something like this:

```
progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle for you to play around with the styling of the different progress bar pseudo elements: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2jha2464/1/

For more information you should read this [post](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) on css-tricks.com